# Avoiding eval in matlab function

Tags: matlab, function, eval

I use the symbolic toolbox in matlab to generate some very long symbolic expressions. Then I use matlabFunction to generate a function file.
Say there are three parameters: p1, p2 and p3.
I have a cell with strings {'p1', 'p2', 'p3'}.
In the derivation of the model I generate symbolic variables p1, p2 and p3 out of them using eval in a loop and stack them in a vector par.
Then when in matlabFunction, I specify par as input.
Moreover, I save the cell string in a .mat file.

Then when I want to simulate this model, I can construct this parameter array using that cell of strings from the .mat file out of 30 available parameters and their values.

Advantages: No need to keep track of the different parameters if I add one to . I can change the order, mess around, but older models still work.
Disadvantage:
Turning things into a function file leads to this error (psi is one of the parameters):

*Error: File: f_derive_model.m Line: 96 Column: 5
"psi" previously appeared to be used as a function or
command, conflicting with its use here as the name of a
variable.
A possible cause of this error is that you forgot to
initialize the variable, or you have initialized it
implicitly using load or eval.*

Apparently some unnescescary checking is going on because the variable will be intialized in an eval statement.

**Question: How can I avoid eval but keep the list of parameters indepent from the model stuff.**

Code deriving the long equations:

```
% Model parameters
mdl.parameters = {'mp','mb','lp','lb','g','d','mP','mM','k','kt'};    

par = [];

for i=1:length(mdl.parameters)
    eval(strcat(mdl.parameters{i}, '=sym(''', mdl.parameters{i}, "');"));
    eval(sprintf(['par = [par;' mdl.parameters{i} '];']));
    end

%% Calculate stuff

matlabFunction(MM,'file',[modelName '_mass'],'vars',{par},'outputs',{'M'});
```

Code using the generated file:

```
    getparams
    load('m3d_1')

    par = [];
    for i=1:length(mdl.parameters)
        eval(sprintf(['par = [par;params.' mdl.parameters{i} '];']));
    end
```

See how, as long as I specify the correct value to for example params.mp, it always gets assigned to the input corresponding to the symbolic variable mp in the par vector. I do not want to lose that and have to keep track of the order and so on, nor do I want to call my functions with all the parameters one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I see nothing wrong in your approach even if the "public opinion" affirms that it's better to avoid using the `eval` function. An alternative would be using the [assignin](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) function as follows:

```
% use 'caller' instead of 'base' if this code runs within a function

for i = 1:numel(mdl.parameters)
    var_name = mdl.parameters{i};
    assignin('base',var_name,sym(var_name));
end
```

In the second case (the one concerning the `par` variable) I would instead use the [getfield](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html) function:

```
par_len = numel(mdl.parameters);
par = cell(par_len,1);

for i = 1:par_len
    par{i} = getfield(params,mdl.parameters{i});
end
```

or, alternatively, this approach:

```
par_len = numel(mdl.parameters);
par = cell(par_len,1);

for i = 1:par_len
    par{i} = params.(mdl.parameters{i});
end
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding the scare quotes. While you may disagree with everyone as a general rule, `eval` creates [documented performance degradation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) because the JIT compiler is disabled for `eval` commands. Given their general prolific use in bulk instantiation or processing of data, which benefit heavily from JIT compilation, this is pretty much never a tradeoff worth making.

Comment: I'm aknowledged about the performance implication that the eval function has and, as far as I remember, not a single script I ever produced uses it. However, I think that a spodaric usage of it, within the context of a controlled environment and very few calls, will harm no one. Especially if you are new to Matlab and can't (or don't have time to) figure out alternative solutions.

Comment: Thank you both. I figured out the second case as well, so consider that one closed. As to the first case, I am well aware of the performance problems and the JIT compiler is precisely what causes the error I only get when calling this code as a function. I am neither new to Matlab and do have the time, but cannot see a solution that is just as flexible and robust. I do not want to have to add a parameter to more than the model parameter list and the value list (getparams) as I am the most significant error source when changing code.